# Updating the tab/file status after saving in a Sublime Text Plugin

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

This may be an old bug; I found [this report](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/156403-save-on-view-leave-dirty-marker-even-if-is_dirty-is-false/). I'm using Sublime 3 but I think this code also works on 2.

When I call `self.view.run_command('save')` within a plugin, the save *does* happen -- I can type the file in a console window and see the results. The dirty flag seems to get cleared. But the tab for the file contains a dot rather than an x, indicating the file hasn't been saved. And sure enough, if you try to close it, it asks if you want to save the file.

Is there any way to refresh the file window so it recognizes that the file has been saved?

Here's my plugin code: (This is my first plugin so please excuse obvious style issues)

```py
# Sublime Text plugin to insert output in the OUTPUT_SHOULD_BE comment
# Bind to key with:
# { "keys": ["f12"], "command": "insert_output" },
import sublime, sublime_plugin, pprint, os, re

class InsertOutputCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

  def run(self, edit):
    outfile = self.view.file_name().rsplit('.')[0] + ".out"
    if not os.path.exists(outfile):
      sublime.error_message("Not Found: " + outfile)
      return
    out_data = open(outfile).read().strip()
    region = self.view.find(r"/\* OUTPUT_SHOULD_BE\n", 0)
    if region:
      self.view.insert(edit, region.end(), out_data)
      self.view.run_command('save')
      self.view.window().focus_view(self.view)
    else:
      sublime.error_message("Not Found: OUTPUT_SHOULD_BE")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is probably a terrible hack, but it works:

```
self.view.run_command("save")
# Refresh the buffer and clear the dirty flag:
sublime.set_timeout(lambda: self.view.run_command("revert"), 10)
```

The `revert` command, which must be delayed in order to work, simply brings back whatever is stored in the file. Since the file *was* successfully saved on disk, this is just the same file that we already see on the screen. In the process, the dirty flag is cleared and the dot on the file tab becomes an x.

Feels very hacky to me and I'd love a more proper solution. But at least it works, ugly or not.